# JavaScript RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I thought I'd try and be clever with some JavaScript and use a regexp instead of repeated use of the indexOf method. I failed. Miserably.

I would like to try and match anything (using the test method) in the following order:

`predefined string + space + forward slash + one digit number: 3-8 + decimal point`

Can someone tell me what the regexp would be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the predefined string is `myString`:

```
/myString \/[3-8]\./
```

Breakdown:

```
myString    - predefined string (including space)
\/          - Forward slash
[3-8]       - A digit (between 3-8)
\.          - A .
```

A good resource for regular expressions is http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Thanks :) One last question, is [x-y] specifically a digit or just an (entire) integer?

Comment: @lpd - neither. It is for a range. You can do [a-z] for all lower case English alphabet, for instance.